# Index out of range when delete cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Hi and hope you'll help.

In every cell I have a text field which responds directly from table view. I save data via closure in cell.

```
cell.tableViewClosure = {[unowned self] in
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    // Singleton
    Strings.shared.strings[indexPath.row] = cell.textField.text!
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

By instance i delete first cell, data array count and number of rows are equal after in log, but if I try to edit text field in last cell and tap return, app crashes with index out of range.

If log during deletion - it is 5 strings in array, but indexPath.row for this proper cell is 5.

But if I reload data in deletion - everything fine with edit last cell but UI is not smooth.

Comment: Just use removeRow(at:) method instead of reload

Comment: @LeoDabus Removing a single row won't cause all of the cells to be reloaded and won't fix the captured index path values. The reason reloading the whole table fixes the problem is that it does fix all of the captured index paths. The problem here is similar to storing the row in the cell's `tag`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `indexPath.row` is captured when you assign the closure, for your last cell, it will have the value "4". If you subsequently delete an earlier cell, the last element in your array is now "3", but the captured value doesn't change; it is still 4.

When you then edit the text field in the last cell, the captured value 4 is used to access your model and you get an array bounds exception.

You can use `indexPath(for:)` to determine the appropriate index path when the closure executes:

```
cell.tableViewClosure = {[unowned self] in
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        Strings.shared.strings[indexPath.row] = cell.textField.text!
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

indexPath.row starts with 0.  So the range will be 0-4.  If you're using 5 strings in an array and using a .count - that will return a 5.

Just do `indexPath.row - 1` to adjust for the off by 1 (index out of range).

Comment: Thanks. But if i try to edit first cell without deletion it will crash as well. It is system bug or i out of leaks catching

Comment: Right.  As it should.  Since you have an off by 1 error.  Did you try my recommendation?

Comment: This answer *introduces* an off-by-1 error, which is why the first cell now causes a crash; you will be trying to access index -1

Comment: This Worked on my tableview with sections to deleted spacific row thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)` to get the current index